# EDITED: Fetching variables with php based on a previous function (SQL statement)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

I have the code below and I just want to call the variables from my dropdown list to a Javascript function so I can manipulate those values.

```
function generateColorList(){
$selectHeaderStr = "<select class='colorlist-items colorlist' name='title'    id='Colorlist' width='250px'>";
$selectHeaderEnd = "</select>";
$qryTitle = getQueryTitle();
$connQuery = getRowByQuery($qryTitle);

echo $selectHeaderStr;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($connQuery)){
    echo "<option  id='" . $row['title'] ."-" . $row['nid'] ."' class='colorlist-item Colorlist' data-times='" . $row['field_paint_times_value'] ."'  data-efficiency='" . $row['field_paint_efficeincy__value'] ."' value='" . $row['title'] ."'>". $row['title'] . "</option>";
    $p = $row[2];echo $p;echo "</br>";
    $q = $row[3];echo $q ;echo "</br>";
}
  echo $selectHeaderEnd;echo '</br>';
  } 
  echo generateColorList();
?>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script>
$('#Colorlist').change(function () {
var selectedValue = (this).val();
alert(selectedValue)};
</script>

<p id="times"></p>
<p id="efficiency"></p>
<p id="times"></p>
</body>
</html>
```